# Why does CORS negotiation occur when making requests for same domain resoures?

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, cors

I'm reading through this Spring Boot Security tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

It it it states:

> You might not see the 401 because the browser treats the home page load as a single interaction, and you might see 2 requests for "/resource" because there is a CORS negotiation.

However the resource is loaded from `localhost` like all the other requests, so why is there a CORS negotiation?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different port or protocol or subdomain also constitutes a different origin within the [**same origin policy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

So if you make request from `http://localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:8080` it is subject to CORS.

Or from `http` to `https`

Or from `http://www.example.com` to `http://example.com`